# Symfony UserBundle view doesn't override fosUserBundle's view

Tags: php, symfony

My Userbundle well extends fosUserBundle and works well.

Problem: My template UserBundle../.../..layout.html.twig does not override my FosUserBundle../.../..layout.html.twig.

It's the same path(/SymfonyProject/src/moi/UserBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig) in my UserBundle.

My website use the FOS template instead of my new one.
I've cleared the cache.

```
<?php 

namespace moi\UserBundle; 

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle; 

class moiUserBundle extends Bundle 
{ 
    public function getParent()
    {
     return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

moiUserBundle.php:

My versions of twig and fosUB in composer.json:

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "~2.0@dev",
    "twig/twig" : "~1.28"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally works by putting the template in : app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig. And copying controllers from FOSUserbundle/Controller to my UserBundle/Controller.

I mixed first and second method advised in the doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html .